# Does the rinkeby test network have swarm?

Tags: swarm, rinkeby

Does the rinkeby test network have Swarm ? If so, how do I synchronise with it using Geth and Swarm binaries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethereum and Swarm networks are independent. You can use Swarm independently of Ethereum. A bit like using FTP and HTTP (this is not very accurate but may convey the point).

However, if you want to resolve ENS addresses, you need to provide the ENS resolver to swarm, which can be done via the `--ens-api` flag.

So you can run the `geth` binary on mainnet or any testnet and use swarm with the `swarm` binary.